# Cycles: Strange effect on glowing object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have the arrow with **glowing** shader. Rendered by **cycles** it looks like this:

[image: Glowing arrow with strange light effect]

You can see the **light rectangles**, I **don't want** there.
**Geometry** of the arrow **looks fine**:

[image: Glowing arrow with strange light effect in edit mode]

**My shader:**

[image: Glowing shader for the arrow]

**The `.blend` file:** https://pasteall.org/blend/ba4cd35ef4d54a5aaa8cad92cdae5c3f

So how can I get rid of theese light rectangles?

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots OK: https://pasteall.org/blend/ba4cd35ef4d54a5aaa8cad92cdae5c3f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the shape of your arrow that you can see by transparency as it is refracted by the *Glass* node. You can either lower down the *IOR* value or increase the *Roughness* of the node to try to decrease this effect. Also, the topology is rather bad but it's not the problem here.

[image]